# Try to make a IF on a page but it dont work

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a small problem with Laravel:

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('contakt/{code?}', function ($code = "null") {
    return view('contakt',compact('code'));
})->name("contakt");
```

And this is my Page:

```
@if (strcmp($code,"success"))
    <div class="contact-form-success alert alert-success d-none mt-4" id="contactSuccess">
        <strong>Success!</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

When i var_dump out on the contact page the content of $code this is the result:

```
.../storage/framework/views/8ebd5bc41eecbc72e9a5480450fe96d3ba115d33.php:81:string 'success' (length=7)
```

so why do it not work? The Content of `strcmp($code,"success")` is 0. I tried everything but without any success (I tried also @if ($code == "success")) :(

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you check the manual for what `strcmp` returns? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: Thanks! Yes it must be zero if its equals. But even if i write @if(strcmp($code, "success")==0) it dont work

Comment: `strcmp($code,"success") === 0`

Comment: check into blade file ... {{dd($code)}} ... check output

Comment: Thanks with three === it worked!

Comment: strcmp() is mostly used for comparing not equal strings, I prefer using strpos for same string compare